# Plotting a nice graph with 3000 rows in dataset with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Dataframe (3440 rows x 2 columns) with two columns (int). I need to plot this data frame with y axis (strain-ylabel ) and x axis (time-xlabel) that is the same with the expecting plot (I will show this figure below as a link). There are several visual problems that I hope you guys can teach and show me with, because I am very week in visualization with Python.

Here is the [datasource:](https://www.gw-openscience.org/GW150914data/P150914/fig2-unfiltered-waveform-H.txt)

Here is the expecting [plot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0pBQ.png)

Here is [result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afHef.png)

Here is my code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('https://www.gw-openscience.org/GW150914data/P150914/fig2-unfiltered-waveform-H.txt')
df= df['index'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
df.coulumns=['time (s)','strain (h1)']
x=df['time'][:200]
y=df['strain'][:200]

plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
plt.scatter(x,y,c='blue')
plt.show()
```

Note: I have tried with seaborn, but result was the same. I also tried to narrow down into 200 rows, but the result is different with the expecting plot.

I appreciate if you guys can help me with. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. I'm skipping the first row, because the column labels are not separated correctly. Furthermore, while loading the data I indicate that the columns are separated by a space.

I don't think that the file contains the data to plot the "reconstructed" line.

```
import pandas as pd

# read the csv file, skip the first row, columns are separated by ' ' 
df=pd.read_csv('fig2-unfiltered-waveform-H.txt', skiprows=1, sep=' ')

# add proper column names
df.columns = ['index', 'strain (h1)']

# extract the index & strain variables
index=df['index']
strain=df['strain (h1)']

# plot the figure
plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
plt.plot(index, strain, c='red', label='numerical relativity')

# label the y axis and show the legend
plt.ylabel('strain (h1)')
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

This is the resulting plot:
[image]

The same with seaborn, once you've imported the data with pandas:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(data = df, x="index", y="strain (h1)", color='red')
```

[image]